# How to solve this no-unsafe-optional-chaining eslint error?

Tags: lint

```
  const { _: slug } = event?.context?.params;
```

Running npm run lint always throws an

```
Unsafe usage of optional chaining. If it short-circuits with 'undefined' the evaluation will throw TypeError  no-unsafe-optional-chaining
```

Error.

Any help would be appreciated.